# VSTS Wiki Preview Incorrect

Tags: azure-devops, wiki

I'm editing a Wiki page and I started to enter a date in YYYY.MM.DD format and the preview is wrong.  Am I doing something wrong?

In the edit page I've got '2017.' but in the preview it reads '17.'.

[image: wiki edit and preview]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I was able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Wiki page treat `2017.` as a number list.
I posted a problem [Format YYYY. in VSTS Wiki page doesn't show correct](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119720/format-yyyy-in-vsts-wiki-page-doesnt-show-correct.html), you can follow up.

But the format for `YYYY.MM.DD` is correct. You can continue entering `MM.DD` (such as `09.26`) following `2017.` (without blank space), the preview will be as expected `2017.09.26`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in the next deployment of VSTS. Thank you for the feedback.